# Build ifuse as standalone executable for MacOS

Tags: macos, makefile, build, libimobiledevice

I built an executable for MacOS using Brew but when I run it, it tries to access Homebrew packages/paths.

```
Library not loaded: /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/homebrew/opt/libimobiledevice/lib/libimobiledevice-1.0.6.dylib
```

Is there a way you to build ifuse as a standalone executable to run on MacOS?

See the install steps here for `ifuse`:
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse#installation--getting-started

Here is the Brew formula:

```json
{
    "name": "ifuse",
    "full_name": "ifuse",
    "tap": "homebrew/core",
    "oldname": null,
    "aliases": [],
    "versioned_formulae": [],
    "desc": "FUSE module for iOS devices",
    "license": "LGPL-2.1",
    "homepage": "https://www.libimobiledevice.org/",
    "versions": {
        "stable": "1.1.4",
        "head": "HEAD",
        "bottle": true
    },
    "urls": {
        "stable": {
            "url": "https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse/archive/1.1.4.tar.gz",
            "tag": null,
            "revision": null
        }
    },
    "revision": 0,
    "version_scheme": 0,
    "bottle": {
        "stable": {
            "rebuild": 0,
            "cellar": ":any",
            "prefix": "/usr/local",
            "root_url": "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles",
            "files": {
                "catalina": {
                    "url": "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ifuse-1.1.4.catalina.bottle.tar.gz",
                    "sha256": "cdce9fc5dbaf44641743b4a77434d340ae11cb8ed98f17b1a86a5653d2b6e1a2"
                },
                "mojave": {
                    "url": "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ifuse-1.1.4.mojave.bottle.tar.gz",
                    "sha256": "e14e4f8e0f73324dc662b47f091261f682eddc73961e3d71a07bfeb62826a1f8"
                },
                "high_sierra": {
                    "url": "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ifuse-1.1.4.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz",
                    "sha256": "ff5577f28749cf18671eecd953e96f0c52a06dccf827dcf08e2d64f894dfdd5e"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "keg_only": false,
    "bottle_disabled": false,
    "options": [],
    "build_dependencies": [
        "autoconf",
        "automake",
        "libtool",
        "pkg-config"
    ],
    "dependencies": [
        "glib",
        "libimobiledevice",
        "libplist"
    ],
    "recommended_dependencies": [],
    "optional_dependencies": [],
    "uses_from_macos": [],
    "requirements": [
        {
            "name": "osxfuse",
            "cask": "osxfuse",
            "download": "https://osxfuse.github.io/",
            "version": null,
            "contexts": []
        }
    ],
    "conflicts_with": [],
    "caveats": null,
    "installed": [],
    "linked_keg": null,
    "pinned": false,
    "outdated": false,
    "deprecated": true,
    "deprecation_date": "2020-11-10",
    "deprecation_reason": "requires FUSE",
    "disabled": false,
    "disable_date": null,
    "disable_reason": null,
    "analytics": {
        "install": {
            "30d": {
                "ifuse": 333,
                "ifuse --HEAD": 154
            },
            "90d": {
                "ifuse": 1176,
                "ifuse --HEAD": 268
            },
            "365d": {
                "ifuse": 8644,
                "ifuse --HEAD": 1295
            }
        },
        "install_on_request": {
            "30d": {
                "ifuse": 333,
                "ifuse --HEAD": 154
            },
            "90d": {
                "ifuse": 1176,
                "ifuse --HEAD": 268
            },
            "365d": {
                "ifuse": 8604,
                "ifuse --HEAD": 1297
            }
        },
        "build_error": {
            "30d": {
                "ifuse": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "generated_date": "2021-03-29"
}
```

Comment: Looks like this may be possible with a untar'd install of brew along with changing brew's cache/install paths: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84403/how-to-use-homebrew-to-install-local-archive

Answer (score 7):

You can now install `ifuse` using Homebrew, without needing to compile it, using this tap: https://github.com/gromgit/homebrew-fuse

```
brew install gromgit/fuse/ifuse-mac
```

Before you do this, ensure that you've removed `osxfuse` and installed `macfuse` (succeeds `osxfuse` as of v4.0.0):

```
brew uninstall osxfuse && \
brew install --cask macfuse
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update***

This still references `osxfuse` at `/usr/local`:

```
file system sandbox blocked open() of \'/usr/local/lib/libosxfuse.2.dylib
```

---

Was able to install `ifuse` with brew all in one folder via the following steps:

- Install untar'd brew in a new folder:

  - `mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew`
  - https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#untar-anywhere
- copy custom `brew.sh` into your `./homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh`, removing sudo check
- `export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="./"`
- `export HOMEBREW_CACHE="./"`
- `sudo ./homebrew/bin/brew install -s -f ifuse`

See Brew Prefix and Cache docs here:

- Prefix: https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#variables-for-directory-locations
- Cache: https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#environment